# Redirect different domains to the same apache using reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, tutum

Morning,

I'm running a dockerized envirovment (localy and on tutum for production) that consists of:

1. nginx reverse proxy with https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy
2. Multiple sets of containers that are mainly websites with apache and things.

The reverse proxy relies on the environment variable VIRTUAL_HOST set on some apaches to redirect traffic and it works well both in development and production using different environment variables thanks to changing between foo.dev and foo.com on developent/production thanks to an aditional production.yml or different configuration on the stackfile on tutum.

But now I need to have both foo.com and foo.es served by the same web app (one will be the translation of the other provided by the same wordpress container).

What I think I need is to define multiple VIRTUAL_HOST on the stackfile/docker-compose.yml but I don't know if it's possible.

Am I missing something?

**Is it possible to route both foo.com and foo.es to the same container with this setup?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I just needed to separate the hosts by comas on the same VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable as stated **in the documentation of the reverse proxy I was using**

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#multiple-hosts

Sorry!